# Parse multiple lines in text file

Tags: string, parsing, powershell

How can I parse this text1.txt:

```
2016-04-06 12:02:32 AM - INFO  – Connected to services
2016-04-06 12:02:47 AM - ERROR – Service exception
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Pooled connection request timed out (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: Pooled connection request timed out
at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword)
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
2016-04-06 12:02:47 AM - WARN  – Unexpected error has occurred. See application logs for more details. Service will wait for 60 seconds and then try again.
2016-04-06 12:07:07 AM - INFO  – Connected to services
2016-04-06 12:07:22 AM - ERROR – Service exception
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Pooled connection request timed out (Fault Detail is equal to An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: Pooled connection request timed out
at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword)
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
2016-04-06 12:07:22 AM - WARN  – Unexpected error has occurred. See application logs for more details. Service will wait for 60 seconds and then try again.
```

This is my current code:

```
function parse-log
{
    param(
        [string]$line
    )

    $data = $line.split(' ') 
    $dateString = '{0} {1} {2}' -f $data[0], $data[1], $data[2]
    $timeStamp = Get-Date -Date $dateString
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TimeStamp = $timeStamp
        Client    = $data[3]
        Message   = $data[4]
    }
}

foreach ( $line2 in $lines2 )
{
    $entry = parse-log -line $line2
}
```

I get errors because it's trying to parse the next line. I need it to parse the next datetime. In addition, how can I split at hyphens (`-`) so I get the following?

```
$timestamp = 2016-04-06 12:02:32 AM
$data[3] = INFO or ERROR
$data[4] = the rest of the string
```

Comment: You get errors because what? Also **what** error?

Comment: Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "   at Oracle.ManagedDataAcce  
.Client.OracleConnection.Open()" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "The string was not recognized 
as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 3.

Comment: Ok, you are looping over every line and not every line has the format you expect. What do you *expect* to happen here?

Comment: Your log messages can span several lines, so you cannot process all lines alike.

Comment: So what can I do to have the output I expect?

Comment: @SumoStash I would rewrite your question. Include the script and text file content you have now, but also communicate clearly what kind of output you're trying to achieve, exactly what errors you are experiencing, and specific questions about the code you are troubleshooting. "how can I parse [blank]" is too vague, and probably wont provoke an answer you are seeking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use a regex to parse the log:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\w{2})\s-\s(\w+)\s+–\s(.+?)(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\w{2}\s-\s|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sA6cI1/1)

And here the script:

```
$content = Get-Content "PATH_TO_YOUR_LOG" -Encoding UTF8

$regex = '(?si)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\w{2})\s-\s(\w+)\s+–\s(.+?)(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\w{2}\s-\s|$)'

$entries = [regex]::Matches($content, $regex)

foreach ($entry in $entries)
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        TimeStamp =  $entry.Groups[1].Value
        Level  = $entry.Groups[2].Value
        Message   =  $entry.Groups[3].Value
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TimeStamp              Level Message                                                                                                                                                       
---------              ----- -------                                                                                                                                                       
2016-04-06 12:02:32 AM INFO  Connected to services                                                                                                                                         
2016-04-06 12:02:47 AM ERROR Service exception System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Pooled connection request timed out (Fault Detail is equal to ...
2016-04-06 12:02:47 AM WARN  Unexpected error has occurred. See application logs for more details. Service will wait for 60 seconds and then try again.                                    
2016-04-06 12:07:07 AM INFO  Connected to services                                                                                                                                         
2016-04-06 12:07:22 AM ERROR Service exception System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Pooled connection request timed out (Fault Detail is equal to ...
2016-04-06 12:07:22 AM WARN  Unexpected error has occurred. See application logs for more details. Service will wait for 60 seconds and then try again.
```

Comment: that's one hell of a regular expression

Comment: I think this perfectly matches the entries. Its also working for multiple lines.  I don't see a better approach.

Comment: do you use a tool to format your regex? If you were doing this from the hip color me impressed.

Comment: What do you mean with format my regex? I postet a link with a Demo to 101regex.com where I created the regex.

Comment: I see. I missed that link before.

Comment: How can I output only the object that has TimeStamp greater than a certain time?

Comment: you have to parse the date using `[DateTime]::Parse()`. You probably should create another question after you tried it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to process lines starting with a date and skip over the other lines, you could do something like this:

```
$pattern = '^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M) - (\w+) +– (.*)'
$lines2 | Where-Object { $_ -match $pattern } | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        TimeStamp = $matches[0]
        Severity  = $matches[1]
        Message   = $matches[2]
    }
}
```

Note that the second dash is not a hyphen, but an en-dash (character U+2013).

Answer (score 0):

A perhaps more direct example using the switch statement which was patterned (to some extent) after AWK.

```
# Switch statement loops over each line in the file
switch -regex (get-content data.txt)
{
    # Makes sure that the line matches
    '^[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]' {
        # split the line with multiple assignement & type constraint
        [datetime] $timestamp, $data1, $data2 = $_ -split ' . '
        # Build the result object
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            timestamp = $timestamp
            data1 = $data1
            data2 = $data2
        }
    }
}
```